# How to make an environment star Exercise?

Tags: environments, starred-version

I want to create an environment star Exercise, but I can not. Please help me.

```
\documentclass{book} 
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[chapter]
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \section{First section}
    \begin{ex}
    This is an Exercise
    \end{ex}

    \begin{ex}
    This is an Exercise
    \end{ex}

    \end{document}
```

If next  is a difficult Exercise, how to define new environment Exercise star, for example `\textbf{Exercise} $1.3^\text{*}$`.

Comment: What do you want? Please explain your intention?

Comment: An alternative to the nice (accepted) answer: write the `ex` environment so that it accepts an optional `*` argument. That's easy with the `xparse` package.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just modify the representation of the counter for difficult exercises:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[chapter]
\newenvironment{ex*}
  {\renewcommand\theex{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}\rlap{$^*$}}\ex}
  {\endex}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{ex}
This is an Exercise
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
This is an Exercise
\end{ex}

\begin{ex*}
This is a difficult Exercise
\end{ex*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If the asterisk is not desired in the references to this exercise, then the definition of `ex*` can be changed into

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{ex*}
  {\renewcommand\theex{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}\rlap{$^*$}}%
   \ex\edef\@currentlabel{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}}}
  {\endex}
\makeatother
```

so that the reference will be created without *.

Comment: I had a problem like this once. I can use it again. Thanks @egreg.

Comment: @hpesoj626 There may be a problem if you want to `\label` the exercise and then refer to it: with this solution the `*` will be printed also by `\ref`. It can be changed, if needed: please, let me know

Comment: Yes I see the `*`. Can you update the answer to so that the asterisk is not included by `\ref`? I was supposed to ask in chat but connection is slow at the moment.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I've put the addition you requested.

Comment: Thanks. What does the new line `\ex\edef\@currentlabel{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}}` actually do? I don't know what `\edef` does to `\@currentlabel`. Is there already a question here or material that explains these? Let me know if I have to ask this in a separate post or in chat. Thanks.

Comment: `\label` uses the current value of `\@currentlabel` to set the text which will be used with a corresponding `\ref`. The command `\refstepcounter` does a similar statement, but in this case we need to override it after the `\ex` macro has set the number. With `\edef` the replacement text is expanded, so we get the current numbers, rather than the macros which we would get with a simple `\def`. Look for `currentlabel` in the site and you'll find several question or answers dealing with it.

Comment: thanks. I will be deleting this last message soon to clean up a bit. But I would retain the others since others might benefit from reading them.

Answer (score 3):

The package `Exercise` can help here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
    This is an exercise.
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[difficulty=1]
    This is a difficult exercise.
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Example of exercise package]

Answer (score 2):

I have just found an answer

```
 \documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[chapter]
\theoremseparator{$^\text{*}$.}
\newtheorem{dex}[ex]{Exercise}

\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Answer}{loigiaichung}
\Newassociation{sols}{ansF}{loigiaichung}         
\newcommand{\preansF}{}                               
\renewcommand{\ansFlabel}[1]{{\bfseries #1*.}}         
\renewcommand{\Answerlabel}[1]{\bfseries #1.}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\Opensolutionfile{loigiaichung}[ex]
\section{First section}
\begin{ex}
This is an exercise
\begin{sol}
This is a solution
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{dex}
This is an exercise
\begin{sols}
This is a solution
\end{sols}
\end{dex}


\chapter{Second Chapter}
\Opensolutionfile{loigiaichung}[ex]
\section{Second  section}
\begin{ex}
This is an exercise
\begin{sol}
This is a solution
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{dex}
This is an exercise
\begin{sols}
This is a solution
\end{sols}
\end{dex}

\Closesolutionfile{loigiaichung}
\section{Hint, anserw}
\input{ex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `$^\text{*}$`, which produces too high an asterisk: either `$^{*}$` or simply `*`. However, the position of the asterisk will be wrong if you use the optional argument to `dex`: `\begin{dex}[From \cite{xyz}]` will have the asterisk after the attribution.

Comment: Despite the formatting discussion in comments, this answer appears to be significantly better than the accepted one?